# Binding to collection that exist in other collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `ListBox` that has binding to the collection (Publishers), every publisher has a name and collection of authors in it, every author has a name. So how can I provide binding to author's name?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding city}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
```

It is binding to a publisher's name and city.

Comment: if you have collection of items use ListView and as ItemSource set ObservableCollection of your object (publlishers?)  in your ViewModel then as ItemTemplate set yours textbblocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding authors}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This will show name of a publisher with a list of all its authors for every publisher. I assumed a publisher has a property named `authors` that returns `IEnumerable<Author>`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this provided that the `Publisher` class, or whatever you call it, exposes the authors using a public collection property that has an indexer:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Publishers}" .... />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Authors[0].Name, ElementName=listBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
```

This will the display the name of the first author at index 0.

If you intend to display all authors of the selected publisher, you should use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Authors, ElementName=listBox}"
                      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: i tried this 



<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.authors, ElementName=MainList}">
                            
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                           
                        </ItemsControl>

But it's not working, its located in listBox DataTemplate

Comment: Okay i'll ask new one

Answer (score 0):

An author would be an element in a collection which is part of a publisher.

So there is no way for WPF to 'know' which author's name to display: there are multiple.

Instead of a textblock, an ItemsControl could be used that binds its ItemsCollection to the collection of authors in the current publisher.